# getting "The resource cannot be found" error when trying to access application hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

My ASP.NET Application uses Windows authentication. I hosted the application in IIS and tried to access the application from the same server. I am able to access the application without error. But when I try to access the same application outside the server I am getting the error below:

> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /FacetsUserSetupApp/home.aspx

The surprising part is I am getting this error only sometimes. It is working fine some other times. I am unsure of how this behavior is occurring.

The IIS trace log shows the below message when the error occurs:

> 2013-06-10 15:14:32 10.0.40.168 GET /FacetsUserSetupApp/Home.aspx - 80
>   - 10.4.43.41 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+InfoPath.3;+MS-RTC+LM+8;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+MS-RTC+LM+8)
>   401 2 5 140
>
> 2013-06-10 15:14:33 ::1 POST /FacetsUserSetupService/Service1.svc - 80
>   - ::1 - 200 0 0 781
>
> 2013-06-10 15:14:33 ::1 POST /FacetsUserSetupService/Service1.svc - 80
>   - ::1 - 200 0 0 15

Please help me resolving this.

Comment: Can you try it in fiddler and see from where its erroring out?

Comment: It seems that you are getting a [401 Unauthorized status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).

Comment: but I am able to Access the application sometimes. this issue is occuring only when i try to access the application through citrix

Comment: Does your IIS application installed locally and accessed locally or install locally and accessed remotely?

Comment: im accessing the app remotely

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are getting a [401.2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273) status code:

> ## HTTP 401.2: Denied by server configuration
>
> **Description**
>
> The client browser and IIS could not agree on an authentication
>   protocol.
>
> **Common reasons**
>
> - No authentication protocol (including anonymous) is selected in IIS. At least one authentication type must be selected. For more
>     information, click the following article number to view the article in
>     the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
>   [253667](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253667) Error message: HTTP 401.2 - Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration
>     with no authentication
> - Only Integrated authentication is enabled, and an older, non-Internet Explorer client browser tries to access the site. This
>     happens because the client browser cannot perform Integrated
>     authentication. To resolve this problem, use one of the following
>     methods:
>
>   - Configure IIS to accept Basic authentication. This should only occur over SSL for security purposes.
>   - Use a client browser that can perform Integrated authentication. Internet Explorer and new versions of Netscape Navigator and Mozilla
>       Firefox can perform Integrated authentication.
> - **Integrated authentication is through a proxy**. This happens because the proxy doesn't maintain the NTLM-authenticated connection
>     and thus sends an anonymous request from the client to the server.
>     Options to resolve this problem are as follows:
>
>   - Configure IIS to accept Basic authentication. This should only occur over SSL for security purposes.
>   - Don't use a proxy.

Probably the problem occurs because of the proxy.

Also just to make sure that everything is properly configured, check these troubleshooting / configuration links:

- [Error message when you try to visit a Web page that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043)
- [Windows Authentication <windowsAuthentication>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication)

Comment: I have enabled Basic Authentication in the server And made NTLM as the first preference in the windows authentication Providers. Yet iam getting the issue.

Comment: I verified the windows authentication setting for the app in IIS . it is set as mentioned in the link mentioned by u. Also Iam able to access the application from some servers outside the hosted servers getting The issue only from some servers.